# Dynamically Loading Form Fields in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic

Kindly pardon me if i looks silly as i am new in PHP and learning stuffs from SO .

I will try to explain clearly as possible what i am into

Currently i have a profile page for different level of users like

> Admin, Level1, Level2, Level3

Fields are not same for all the 4 profile pages .

> For level 1 i will display Name,Age,Picture

and

> For Level 2 i will display Name,Picture,Location,Country

and

> some other for Level3

The above i have done and it's working without any issues .

Now what i need was to make the admin to select the form fields dynamically . Like , there should be a setting kind of page in admin where i will list all the needed fields for different level of users under the level name with a check box near it(which i done).

Now the confusion was the admin can check what fields needed and that will reflect in that profile page of that user , Which i am confused on how to proceed as i cant get any idea on how to proceed . Also he should be able to add extra field (text box only allowed) like he will click add and enter the label name . this newly added text box should be functional like storing the value in db and retrieving.

Hope i explained clearly . if you are not clear with any stuffs kindly pardon me and make a comment i will explain further on that .

I needed help on getting a idea or structure on how to proceed for my requirement.

Comment: You can create a table in your database, a column for the input type, a column for the name tag, and a column for the privilege of who will use this field.

Comment: @LoganWayne Thanks mate for the idea. i will work on that and will let you know how it comes up. 

Can you kindly help with an idea of adding the field by himself as i mentioned in last paragraph

Comment: Are you referring to the admin or to the user when you said that `adding the field by himself`?

Comment: @LoganWayne admin mate

Comment: You can just add a new field to the `input_tb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table in your database, a column for the input type, a column for the name tag, and a column for the privilege of who will use this field.

Table (`input_tb`) will look like this:

```
input_id | input_type | name_tag |   label  |  user_type
---------+------------+----------+----------+-------------
    1    |    text    |   name   |   Name   |     1 /* ASSUMING 1 IS FOR LEVEL 1 PROFILE */
    2    |   number   |   age    |    Age   |     1
    3    |    file    |  picture |  Picture |     1
```

Assuming your `user_tb` looks like this:

```
user_id | user_type
--------+-----------
   1    |     1 /* MEANS THAT USER 1 HAS A LEVEL 1 PROFILE */
```

So, when a user accessed the form, you fetch the corresponding rows in the `input_tb` (*assuming you store the `user_type` on a session below*):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT input_id, input_type, name_tag, label FROM input_tb WHERE user_type = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["user_type"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($inputid, $inputtype, $nametag, $label);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo $label.': <input type="'$inputtype..'" name="'.$nametag.'"><br>';
}
$stmt->close();
```

Then, the information will be stored in another table:

Example of `info_tb`, using a single sample user here:

```
info_id | user_id | input_id |   input_data 
--------+---------+----------+-----------------
   1    |    1    |    1     |    Richard      /* User 1's Name */
   2    |    1    |    2     |       18        /* User 1's Age */
   3    |    1    |    3     | profile_pic.png /* User 1's Picture */
```

#### Reminder:

- You can also consider having a condition to your code, when an input field is a `textarea`
- Put a condition, when an input field is a file type. It has to go the process of uploading before inserting the corresponding file name to the database

Comment: Really thanks a lot mate. as per your answer i will proceed and will update the status here mate